# Python Pandas printing out values of each cells

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fetch values from an excel file using pandas dataframe and print out the values of each cells.
Im using `read_excel()` to populate the dataframe, and
I am looking for specific rows using the following line of code:

```
df.loc[df['Parcel_ID'] == parcel]
```

parcel being an arbitrary input from the user. And I simply use this to print out the cells:

```
row = df.loc[df['Parcel_ID'] == parcel]

print row['Category']
print row['Sub_Category']
.
.
(more values)
```

What I want is only the values from the cells, yet I get dtypes, names of the column, and other junks that I don't want to see. How would I only print out the value from each cells?

Comment: Could you please add a sample input and the according desired output to your question? I think we could solve this a lot easier if knowing what we want to get...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have several values in your row you could use following:

```
row['Category'].values.tolist()
row['Sub_Category'].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC the following should work:

```
print row['Category'][0]
print row['Sub_Category'][0]
```

what is returned will be a Series in your case a Series with a single element which you index into to return a scalar value

Answer (score 0):

How to find a value in a column (Column 1 name) by another value in another column (Column 2 name)

```
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsm','SheetName') #Get a excel file sheet
```

Then you have two ways to get that:

First Way:

```
    Value_Target = df.loc[df['Column1name']== 'Value_Key']['Column2name'].values
```

Second Way:

```
    Value_Target = df['Column1name'][df['Column2name']=='Value_Key'].values[0]
```

Value_Key is the value in a column you have
Value_Target is the value you want to find using Value_Key